# Ruby Eglot Tree-Sitter Configuration

Tags: eglot, ruby, tree-sitter

Has anyone managed an eglot and tree-sitter configuration for ruby that has a reasonably full feature set.  I have both activated, but here are some things that don't work:

- xref jumping
- code folding
- documentation

I have tried both ruby-lsp and solargraph, but I get "Capability" errors with both in the Eglot buffer.

Thought I would toss this out there for the community to come up with a good config.

UPDATE: When I try to M-> to an xref, I get the following in the eglot event buffer:

```
[client-request] (id:27) Thu Sep 21 11:40:03 2023:
(:jsonrpc "2.0" :id 27 :method "textDocument/definition" :params
          (:textDocument
           (:uri "file:///home/ded/src/byr/lib/byr/models/account.rb")
           :position
           (:line 807 :character 29)))
[server-reply] (id:27) Thu Sep 21 11:40:03 2023:
(:id 27 :result nil :jsonrpc "2.0")
[server-notification] Thu Sep 21 11:40:03 2023:
(:method "telemetry/event" :params
         (:request "textDocument/definition" :lspVersion "0.8.1" :requestTime 0.017213684041053057 :uri "~/src/byr/lib/byr/models/account.rb")
         :jsonrpc "2.0")
```

The reply looks empty.

Comment: I think the best way to proceed is to file a report against Eglot, with all associated information that they ask for when creating an issue (those would be your minimal settings and language server logs, mostly).

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think I have an error, however, just an inadequate config, and thought I would first see if everyone else sees the same thing, or I'm just missing something.  If this bears no fruit, I might follow your suggestion.  Cheers.

Comment: When I try solargraph with Eglot (v. 0.49.0), it mostly works (both xref jumping and documentation, type `M-x eldoc` for the latter, or `M-x eldoc-doc-buffer`). Solargraph sometimes has difficulties jumping to methods from gems (especially using macros), but inside the project the basics should work, no particular config required. No idea about code folding.